# Callback between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I'm trying to pass a object between 2 fragments and but i keep on getting null pointer exception when executing the callback:
Code:

```
mCallback.clipboardCreated(currentClipboardVO);
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myapp.fragments.AddClipboardFragment.onAPIResponse(AddClipboardFragment.java:256)
```

Here is is how I define the callback

```
public interface OnClipboardCreated {

        public void clipboardCreated(ClipboardVO clipboard);
    }
```

so my question is, should I define the callback - is that why i get NPE? If so how can I initialize the callback?

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `mCallback`?

Comment: @Tanis.7x how do you mean? i think i dont do that - can you tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Well, somewhere you should be saying `mCallback = something`. If you never assign a value to `mCallback`, then anything you do with `mCallback` is guaranteed to throw a NullPointerException, as `mCallback` doesn't have a value.

Comment: @Tanis.7x can I get the values from the callback in another fragment? Or I should get this in the activity?

Comment: Presumably you have a class somewhere that implements `OnClipboardCreated`. The value you assign to `mCallback` should be an instance of that class. How you get an instance of that class is up to you and is dependent on what you are doing.

Comment: Usually you would let the Activity handle inter-fragment communication. But you could look into EventBus. EventBus makes it easy to pass any object around in your app.